# Fresh Install of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (No Dual Boot) - Getting No Bootable Device

Tags: 14.04, boot, acer, aspire

Really hoping some one can assist as I'm concerned that I have done something wrong with my new installation of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, with no dual boot on my Acer Aspire ES1-512-C32A.

Basically, when I remove my Live USB Flash drive and reboot, press F2 for BIOS, I change boot order to used my HDD, see nothing that mentions Ubuntu Boot or anything relating to Ubuntu, so just choose my HDD name - save changes, machine reboots and straight off, just get the message "**No Bootable Device**"

Have tried to search other similar threads but am not understanding exactly what I need to do.

I see something like using efibootmgr, which I assume has to performed from Live USB bootup but receive the message: command not found.

Really keen to get this working on my Acer Aspire but would really appreciate the required steps to fix this issue, which again, I assume will be from my bootable Ubuntu flash drive.

Simple steps would really be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried running boot repair?

Comment: Hi, not sure what that is and how to run it. Can you pls assist. Also, this is not a dual boot.

Comment: I'm on a phone with poor editing power. Google for boot repair, there is an official ubuntu page on it. Basically you boot the live usb, install this tool, and run it.

Comment: Thanks. Have just performed the Boot Repair process and came back with Boot successfully repaired and that I can now reboot. Now, do I need to change BIOS Boot order as it's currently pointing to my USB Flash Drive?

Comment: I would set the bios as you plan to have it in the final config and try a reboot.

Comment: Really appreciate your help but I do not understand what you mean with regards to final config. I actually rebooted my machine with Live USB out, but was first presented with a screen that said 1) "Shim UEFI Key Management" then was presented with 2) Boot Manager screen with two options: a) Unknown Device and b) Windows Boot Manager. Selected "Unknown Device" as option (b) did nothing. After this, saw a GRUB ver 2.02 screen with the first option of *Ubuntu, which then eventually got me into Ubuntu. Why all these steps? Do you need to see my Boot Repair pastebin file?

Comment: I'm not that sophisicated of a user.  Since you can now boot to Ubuntu, my advice is to post a different question about this boot scenario you have. I'll put my boot repair suggestion as an answer and you can accept it  if you like.

Comment: ok - good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running boot repair as a first step.  Google for the official boot repair ubuntu page.  Sorry I can't post a fancier answer, I am on a phone.